# Last Entry in Stored Procedure does not Update

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have written below stored procedure, it works well, however, it does not update the last entry in string. Any ideas why?

```
create procedure testProceduretwo 
    @vendorIds varchar(max)
as
    declare @pos int
    declare @vendor varchar(50)
    set @pos = charindex(',', @vendorIds)

    while @pos <> 0
    begin
        set @vendor = left(@vendorIds, @pos-1)
        exec ('update DS_REGISTERED_VENDOR set ppu_flag=''Y'' where Vendor_Id = ' + @vendor + '')
        print 'updated vendor id - ' + @vendor

        set @vendorIds = stuff(@vendorIds, 1, @pos, NULL)
        set @pos = charindex(',', @vendorIds)
    end

    exec ('update DS_REGISTERED_VENDOR set ppu_flag=''Y'' where Vendor_Id = ' +  @vendor + '')
```

I call it using this:

```
exec testProceduretwo '00072211,00000004,00120188,00000001'
```

It does not update the value for - 00000001 (last entry)

Comment: Gah, so many problems with this. Firstly, using a `WHILE` to loop through delimited data is an awfully slow way to go about it. Next, what you have here is very open to injection.

Comment: Curious. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite this to be far safer, and quicker by doing this:

```
CREATE PROC testProceduretwo @vendorIds varchar(max) AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE DS
    SET ppu_flag = 'Y'
    FROM DS_REGISTERED_VENDOR DS
         CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@vendorIds,',') SS --Assumes SQL Server 2016+
    WHERE SS.[value] = DS.Vendor_Id;
END
GO
```

If you aren't using SQL Server 2016 then you can use an XML Splitter, or `delimitedsplit8k(_lead)`. A quick google will find either of these.

Answer (score 0):

...Because you use charindex

```
set @pos = charindex(',', @vendorIds)
```

to find the first comma, and then take everything that is before it (left):

```
set @vendor = left(@vendorIds, @pos-1)
```

The fastest way would be to manually add a comma at procedure start:

```
(......)
declare @pos int
set @vendorIds+=',' -- add this row
declare @vendor varchar(50)
(......)
```

This is just a functional reasoning, consider Larnu's warnings too.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problems I mentioned though. A `WHILE` will be inherently slow here and this still leaves it open to injection.